# Form-mailer Inbox-display issue

Tags: php, email

The line of code below is part of the form-mailer that processes the form on my Website. Whenever I receive an E-mail from the form, I can't see the name of the sender until I open the email because it displays(Inbox display) just the E-mail address and the Subject. How do I get it to display the Name and the Subject(Inbox display), so that I'll know the sender before I open it. I'd also like it to be reply-ready, So it replies to the sender's email When I Click on reply.

```
 $message = "\n$fname submitted the following message:\n\n$message\n\n$fname's contact details are as follows:\n\nFirst Name: $fname\nLast Name: $lname\nPhone Number: $phone\nEmail Address: $email\n";

  mail($mailto, "$subject", $message, "From: $email");

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mail($mailto, $subject, $message, "From: Person's Name<$email>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in this way also:

A) In Your Code:

```
$mail->FromName = "Name Of Mailer";
```

B) In Phpmailer:

```
public $FromName = 'Terasoft';    //Root User
```

Hope this May work For you.